# Garbage values are being output in 2D Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I want to make a program that calculates and prints a multiplication table for all values between 1 and 10, however, in the last table(table of 10) I am having problems, garbage values are shown.

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     const int numRows=10;
     const int numCols=10;     
     int product[numRows][numCols];
    for (int row= 1 ; row <= numRows; ++row)
    {
        for (int col= 1 ; col <= numCols; ++col)
        {
            product[row][col] = row * col;
        }
     }
    for (int row= 1 ; row <=numRows; ++row)
    {
        for (int col= 1 ; col <= numCols; ++col)
        {
            std::cout << product[row][col] << '\t';
        } 
        cout << '\n';
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that C/C++ arrays start at index 0? Resp. the last element of an array with N elements has index N-1. Accessing element with index N in an array with N elements is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Indexes start at 0.  `for(int row = 0; ...`

Comment: Change `for (int row= 1 ; row <= numRows; ++row)` to `for (int row= 0 ; row < numRows; ++row)` and similar for the cols

Comment: it still doesn't work if I replace row =1 and col =1 with row =0 and col =0 in both the loops.

Comment: You may want  to change this line too `product[row][col] = row * col;` . Unless you wanted to see 0 x 0 in your table.. Another source of error is if you did not change `row <= numRows;` to `row < numRows;`